# I get expected indentation block at line

Tags: python-2.7

```
#C:/Python32

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name  = "joe" , age= 20 , salary=0):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.salary = salary
    def __printData__(self):
        return " My name is {0}, my age is {1} , and my salary is {2}.".format(self.name, self.age, self.salary)
    print(Person)

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age , salary ):
        Person. __init__ (self,name = "Mohamed"  , age = 20 , salary = 100000)
        def __printData__(self):
        return " My name is {0}, my age is {1} , and my salary is {2}.".format(sef.name, self.age, self.salary)
    print(Employee)
```

Comment: because you missed an indentation at line before last.

Comment: At the end of both Person and Employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indent the second line here, from:

```
def __printData__(self):
return " My name is {0}, my age is {1} , and my salary is {2}.".format(sef.name, self.age, self.salary)
```

to:

```
def __printData__(self):
    return " My name is {0}, my age is {1} , and my salary is {2}.".format(sef.name, self.age, self.salary)
```

Comment: Fixed it and added new objects for each class but tells me person not found

Comment: class Person:def __init__(self, name  = "joe" , age= 20 , salary=0):
  self.name = name
  self.age = age
  self.salary = salary
 def __printData__(self):
  return " My name is {0}, my age is {1} , and my salary is {2}.".format(self.name, self.age, self.salary)
 print(Person)

class Employee(Person):
 def __init__(self, name, age , salary ):
  Person. __init__ (self,name = "Mohamed"  , age = 20 , salary = 100000)
  def __printData__(self):
   return " My name is {0}, my age is {1} , and my salary is {2}.".format(self.name, self.age, self.salary)
 print(Employee)


p= Person()
e = Employee()

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the second to last line because it is after a function definition.  Also, at one point you use `sef` instead of `self`.  I've corrected both of these below:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name  = "joe" , age= 20 , salary=0):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.salary = salary
    def __printData__(self):
        return " My name is {0}, my age is {1} , and my salary is {2}.".format(self.name, self.age, self.salary)
    print(Person)

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age , salary ):
        Person. __init__ (self,name = "Mohamed"  , age = 20 , salary = 100000)
        def __printData__(self):  # The problem was the line after this one.
            return " My name is {0}, my age is {1} , and my salary is {2}.".format(self.name, self.age, self.salary)
    print(Employee)
```